# Add class for password input in FOS Userbundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to override default registration form of FOS Userbundle and add a custom class to password input. So I've copied register.html.twig and register_content.html.twig into appropriate directory and edited  register_content.html:

```html
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

<form action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="fos_user_registration_register">
    {{ form_errors(form) }}

    {{ form_row(form.email, {'attr': {'class': 'input-block-level'}}) }}
    {{ form_row(form.username, {'attr': {'class': 'input-block-level'}}) }}
    {{ form_row(form.plainPassword, {'attr': {'class': 'input-block-level'}}) }}

    {#{{ form_row(form.submit, { 'label': 'Submit me' }) }}#}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}" />
    </div>
```

`{'attr': {'class': 'input-block-level'}}` -> it works for each input except plainPassword. I guess its because its repeated or something like that. Whats more after removing form_row with plainPassword and clearing cache its still displayed so it seems to come from another file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't come from another file, when you call formend it will render all your fields that you didn't render yet.
to add a class to your plainPassword field you should do it to each element of it because the plain password is an array containing two fields (the password field and the confirm password field).
to do so you need to do something like this :

```
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first, { 'attr': {'class': 'myclass'} }) }}
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second, { 'attr': {'class': 'myclass'} }) }}
```